# auto-commit Teradata SQL Assistant

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Is it possible to disable auto-commit functionality in Teradata SQL Assistant by changing some parameter ?
I have looked through the Teradata SQL Assistant menu, but I don't see such a checkbox as in Teradata Studio.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's your exact issue? ANSI mode or Teradata mode session?

Comment: I don't want the Teradata SQL Assistant to automatically commit DML statements.
It doesn't matter if these are ANSII or Teradata.Net sessions mode

Comment: There's no .Net session. If you run an ANSI mode session SQLA auto-commits (you might run multiple statements as a Multi Statement Request to avoid it), but a Teradata-mode session commits every request automatically (you can use BT/ET then).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of to achieve this is by setting the transaction mode to ANSI.

Though I suggest you check the documentation because ANSI mode has its quirks.

https://docs.teradata.com/reader/8mHBBLGP88~HK9Auie2QvQ/kdzcOoHlpcaoa_NVApG4Pg

Comment: Even in ANSI mode, SQLA (or more accurately, the .NET or ODBC driver) will auto-commit by default. If you want multi-statement transactions in ANSI mode, there are special  directives available in SQLA (.BeginTx, .CommitTx, .RollbackTx) that function similar to Teradata-mode BT, ET, ABORT.

Comment: True, it's not exactly disabling auto-commit. Though ANSI mode will provide some control on the commit. Again, its the closest thing I can think of.

Comment: With the CLIv2 driver, ANSI mode does provide implicit transaction start / explicit COMMIT. But standard APIs like ODBC, JDBC, etc. specify auto-commit as the default behavior - so those drivers actually insert a COMMIT under the covers unless the application specifically requests that auto-commit be disabled.